# Scanning available bluetooth devices for Android in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, android-arrayadapter

I would like to scan available bluetooth deivces and display them in a list. I am newbie to andriod development. I guess that there is some problem with the ArrayAdapter, but not able to figure out the exact problem.

When I run the program, I am getting an exception `The application stops unexpectedly`. Can you help me in solving this.

```
     button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @SuppressWarnings("null")
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView1);
                    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                    // If there are paired devices
                    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) 
                    {
                        // Loop through paired devices
                        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) 
                        {
                            ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter = null;
                            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
                            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                            /*final ArrayList<String> btDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
                            ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CalcActivity.this,
                                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                                    btDevices);
*/
                            lv1.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

I am getting exception at `mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());`

**Edit:**
 Refrained my code but still I am not able to figure out the problem.

[Discovering available bluetooth devices in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924825/discovering-available-bluetooth-devices-in-android)

Comment: Post your LogCat output.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included the `Bluetooth` and `Bluetooth_Admin` permissions in your manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake I guess so is that the `arrayadapter` is not yet initialized
so initialize it(assign it a valid reference of `arrayadapter` a *class*) like this

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,android.R.id.text1,list_names);
```

so now use this to populate your list view of bluetooth devices...