# Discovering available bluetooth devices in android

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth

I just started learning Android development. I am writing an Android program to scan available bluetooth devices and list them in a log file. As I am new to Android, I am unable to figure out what is wrong in the below code snippet.

```
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView1);
                BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();


                final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
                { 
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
                    {
                        String action = intent.getAction(); 
                        // When discovery finds a device 
                        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) 
                        {
                        // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent 
                        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(
                        BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                        Log.v("BlueTooth Testing",device.getName() + "\n"
                        + device.getAddress()); 
                        }
                    }    
                };

                String aDiscoverable = BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE;
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(aDiscoverable),DISCOVERY_REQUEST);
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND); 
                registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); 
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            }
        });
```

When I try the debug mode, the control skips the "`BroadcastReceiver()`". I could not find any entries in the log. Can you help me in figuring out what the problem is and how I can list the available bluetooth devices.

[edit]
I am getting error that the application has stopped unexpectedly:

```
Logcat Errors:
10-28 20:08:24.201: ERROR/UpdateReceiver(914): ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
10-28 20:08:28.415: ERROR/RequestPermissionActivity(431): Timeout = 120
10-28 20:08:44.291: ERROR/DTUN_HCID4(521): === dtunops_stop_discovery() ===
```

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this question with basic4android. If you do want to implement it with Basic4android you should see this [manual](http://www.basic4ppc.com/android/help/serial.html#bluetoothadmin).

Comment: Sorry I was new to android and I thought that Basic4android is a place to get answers relating to basic android programming. I want to solve this using Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions in your manifest